# Merging data in mySQL when not all data points match

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have two tables, Arb_Total and AwardsPlayers. Both tables share the column playerID. I would like to add the column awardID from AwardsPlayers to Arb_Total, linked by playerID. The problem is that only a few of the players in Arb_Total have any awards in AwardsPlayers.

When I run code like:

```
select *
from Arb_Total a, AwardsPlayers w
where a.playerID = w.playerID
```

I only get the results from players who have an award. How would I match the player to the award they won, while keeping all the players who did not win an award?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be looking for a left join...

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp